# Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Can anyone tell me why the following code

```
function s3()

   function ret = fun(x)
       disp(x);
       ret = 0;
   end

  fun(1);

end
```

produces "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.".
I have this code in a file called s3.m. If I run this in the editor
using the play button it runs fine. If I enter s3.m on the command
line it produces the above error.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: the n-th: Possibly 'clear all' might help. Is there a variable  called 's3' in your workspace?

Comment: You must type not `s3.m` but `s3()` in the command line to run the function `s3`

Comment: You asked this same question on the matlab newsgroup. The answer there is you are probably trying to run your function by calling s3.m in the command window. This is not how you execute a function in matlab. If you are going to ask a question, at least read the responses!

Comment: Calling s3.m on the command line yields the following error message: '??? Undefined variable "s3" or class "s3.m".'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call it this way:

```
s3()
```

rather than

```
s3.m
```

because it's a function you have created.